# Can not pass the string widget to webview_flutter

Tags: flutter, variables, widget

I can not pass the widget webDon that is a String. How can I solve it?. Thanks

[image]

[image]

Comment: What error does it show?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the const. Because your displayText is not const. Try this one..

```
return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: SafeArea(
        child: Scaffold(
          body: WebView(
            initialUrl: displayText,
            javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
```